# What does it look like when a file is opened with a pyinstaller exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When a create an exe with pyinstaller, I can associate a file type with the exe (eg .timers):
[image: Associating a file type with application]

When I try to open the file with the program it gives me an error as I would expect:
[image: Fatel error]

But how does Windows pass file paths to the exe? Is there a way to pass the file path to my code?